# handling exception and transaction

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

As you suggessted I have saparted I Splitted insert and exception in to two functions and used COMMIT.
But throwing error.

ErrMsg: invalid transaction termination.

The insert should happen in customer table.
And raise "Invalidpay" error as  p_paid is 0.

```
create or replace  function creatpayment_dest_function(p_acn IN  VARCHAR,
                                           p_seq   IN  NUMERIC,
                                           p_paid IN NUMERIC,
                                           p_seq_ot OUT numeric) AS
    $body$
    declare
    errmsg text;
    v_ctx text;
    p_pmny numeric:=100;
BEGIN 
insert into customer values(100,'CXS'); 
commit;  
exception
            when raise_exception then
              get STACKED diagnostics errmsg = MESSAGE_TEXT, 
                                      v_ctx = PG_EXCEPTION_CONTEXT;
              errmsg := set_context(errmsg,v_ctx);
              raise exception e'%', errmsg;
            when others then
              get STACKED diagnostics errmsg = MESSAGE_TEXT, 
                                      v_ctx = PG_EXCEPTION_CONTEXT;
              errmsg := set_context(errmsg,v_ctx);
              raise exception e'%', errmsg;
END; end $body$ language plpgsql;


create or replace  function creatpayment_dest_exception(p_paid)
AS
$body$
BEGIN 
if (coalesce(p_paid, 0) = 0) then
v_errorMsg:= gnvgen.createerrormessage( 'Invalidpay');    
raise exception e'%',v_errorMsg;
end if;     
        exception
            when raise_exception then
              get STACKED diagnostics errmsg = MESSAGE_TEXT, 
                                      v_ctx = PG_EXCEPTION_CONTEXT;
              errmsg := set_context(errmsg,v_ctx);
              raise exception e'%', errmsg;
            when others then
              get STACKED diagnostics errmsg = MESSAGE_TEXT, 
                                      v_ctx = PG_EXCEPTION_CONTEXT;
              errmsg := set_context(errmsg,v_ctx);
              raise exception e'%', errmsg;
END; end $body$ language plpgsql;
```

Comment: Please come up with a minimal complete code sampe that illustrates your problem. Nobody wants to read through that wad of code.

Comment: I have edited my post. After exception is raised the data inserted in the Payment table is roll backed. Even exception is raised what ever data inserted in the table it should be there as we need it for further processing.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems:

1. You use `RAISE` in the exception handler.
2. You have the `INSERT` that you want to keep in the block with the exception handler.

If you `RAISE` and exception in the exception handler, that will cause the function to fail with an error, which means that the **whole transaction** is rolled back.

The code should look like that:

```
BEGIN
   PERFORM ctpay_function(...);

   BEGIN
      PERFORM allocpaymentNIC_function(...);
   EXCEPTION
      WHEN ... THEN
         /* log the error somewhere */
   END;
END;
```

Logging the error could mean inserting something into a table or using `RAISE NOTICE` or `RAISE WARNING` which will not cause an error message.

Comment: I tried to put one more begin and end getting error SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "if"

Comment: If I am not putting one more begin and end not getting any error. Please help me.

Comment: In Execution1 I have to show the error .In Execution1: creatpayment_dest_function with p_acn=1234,pseq=2,p_paid=null. In that the function ctpay_function inserting data in a Payment table. The function assignbill_function raises exception as invalidpaiderror since p_paid is null.

This is expected scenario. The error I have to capture.

Comment: If you need to have an exception, but want to retain the `INSERT`, you cannot do that in a single function. Split the work into two functions and `COMMIT` between the two function calls.

Comment: Hi ,

As you suggessted I have saparted I Splitted insert and exception in to two functions and used COMMIT.
But throwing erro.

ErrMsg: invalid transaction termination.

The insert should happen in customer table.
And raise "Invalidpay" error as  p_paid is 0. I have edited my post. Please help me.

Comment: You cannot `COMMIT` in a function. You must do that in client code, outside of function calls.

Comment: Can u plz provide an example